# Parallels Won't Stop Throwing the Same Error

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, virtual-machine, parallels

I've been running parallels for about three months with no problems.  Today, upon booting up OS X (before opening parallels) I got this message:

[image]

When I click "ignore" the message reappears in ~10 seconds.  The same thing happens when I click "reopen".

I have tried opening parallels, but that doesn't solve it.  However, when I open paralells, I do keep getting this message:

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

In case it's helpful, I'm pasting below the details that are shown when I click "report" in the error message:

```
Process:         prl_naptd [441] Path:
/Library/Parallels/Parallels
Service.app/Contents/PlugIns/Parallels
NAPT
Service.app/Contents/MacOS/prl_naptd
Identifier:      prl_naptd Version:   
??? (???) Code Type:       X86-64
(Native) Parent Process:  launchd
[152]

Date/Time:       2011-03-27
14:56:49.795 -0400 OS Version:     
Mac OS X 10.6.7 (10J869) Report
Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:         
1044 sec Crashes Since Last Report:   
213 Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:
107 Anonymous UUID:                   
9239A3A6-AA53-4332-A9B9-4F3840263FA0

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS
(SIGSEGV) Exception Codes:
KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at
0x0000000048b936d2 Crashed Thread:  0 
Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue:
com.apple.main-thread 0  
com.parallels.naptd          
    0x0000000100074faf start + 452143 1  
com.parallels.naptd          
    0x000000010009c380 start + 612864 2  
com.parallels.naptd          
    0x00000001000175e5 start + 68709 3  
com.parallels.naptd          
    0x000000010001c57a start + 89082 4  
com.parallels.naptd          
    0x00000001000069b4 start + 52 ...
```

Comment: Could you please make a problem report and send number here. We are unable to help without this information.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a possible solution. Please try the following instructions:

Start `/Application/Utilities/Terminal` and execute these four commands:

```
mkdir -p tmp

cp "/Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/PlugIns/Parallels NAPT Service.app/Contents/MacOS/prl_naptd" ~/tmp/prl_naptd_orig

ditto --arch i386 "/Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/PlugIns/Parallels NAPT Service.app/Contents/MacOS/prl_naptd" ~/tmp

sudo cp ~/tmp/prl_naptd "/Library/Parallels/Parallels Service.app/Contents/PlugIns/Parallels NAPT Service.app/Contents/MacOS/prl_naptd"
```

Enter the password after the last command (please note you will not see it on typing)

Send a problem report if this doesn't help as Den has suggested.